Trying to link 2 tables and getting repeats of rows

I am trying to get back only a single row per Hospital in SQL, but the Database system keeps giving me the number of rows that is in one of the tables with a lot of Nulls. Not sure what I am doing wrong
Select
Name,

Address,

CASE When dbo.organizationprofile.ItemID='9A4BC5A9-D5BA-4ABD-8722-7F493F941577' THEN dbo.organizationprofile.ValueText END As [Trauma Center],

Case When dbo.organizationprofile.ItemID='49408A41-E7A2-4036-BAF3-AFBD93B319D2' THEN dbo.organizationprofile.ValueText END AS [Number of Floors],

Case When dbo.organizationprofile.ItemID='D34B1D5F-630C-4375-8530-7D2A759B7E2F' THEN dbo.organizationprofile.ValueText END AS [Classification]

FROM dbo.organization

JOIN dbo.organizationprofile

On dbo.Organization.ID = dbo.organizationprofile.ID

WHERE Active=1


Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted

Group by ID, Name, and address and take the max value of the other columns.
--New query
Select
Name,
Address,
max(CASE When dbo.organizationprofile.ItemID='9A4BC5A9-D5BA-4ABD-8722-7F493F941577' THEN dbo.organizationprofile.ValueText END) As [Trauma Center],
max(Case When dbo.organizationprofile.ItemID='49408A41-E7A2-4036-BAF3-AFBD93B319D2' THEN dbo.organizationprofile.ValueText END) AS [Number of Floors],
max(Case When dbo.organizationprofile.ItemID='D34B1D5F-630C-4375-8530-7D2A759B7E2F' THEN dbo.organizationprofile.ValueText END) AS [Classification]
FROM dbo.organization
JOIN dbo.organizationprofile
On dbo.Organization.ID = dbo.organizationprofile.ID
WHERE Active=1
GROUP BY organization.ID,Name,Address
ORDER BY organization.ID

Fiddle



Name
Address
TraumaCenter
NumberofFloors
Classification




ChildrensHospital
123MainStreet
Yes
4
A


AdultsHospital
987SouthLane
No
5
B



